# Nagios check_http configuration error

Tags: nagios

I have to remove custom HTTP check from nagios so commented check_http part in two files namely
1. commands.cfg
2. services.cfg

However when I restarted server, I get following error.

```
Checking objects...
Error: Service check command 'check_http' specified in service 'HTTP' for host 'localhost' not defined anywhere!
    Checked 225 services.
    Checked 66 hosts.
    Checked 11 host groups.
    Checked 6 service groups.
    Checked 16 contacts.
    Checked 21 contact groups.
    Checked 29 commands.
    Checked 5 time periods.
    Checked 0 host escalations.
    Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
    Checked 66 hosts
    Checked 0 service dependencies
    Checked 0 host dependencies
    Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...
```

So kindly assist to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..But you haven't removed it from host configuration. If a service is associated with one or more hosts then you will also need to remove the service from them otherwise you will get similar error.

> Error: Service check command 'check_http' specified in service 'HTTP'
>   for host 'localhost' not defined anywhere!

As the error clearly mentions, you have this service configured for host `localhost`. So check the file (localhost.cfg or hosts.cfg), remove the HTTP service and restart nagios.

Comment: Thanks... yes you are right...one entry was remained in localhost.cfg and this file was outside of my custom configuration folder.

So when I grep http it was giving result in that folder only.. so I cam out of folder and again grep and found entry in localhost.cfg and issue is resolved. thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad that it helped.